# Newcommand with dialogue not working

Tags: macros, dialogue

I m trying to create a new short command for the `dialogue` package.  While the regular use of `\speak{}`  inside the environment works, the `\newcommand` that I have created using it doesn't.

```
\newcommand*\tchr{{\speak{Teacher}}}
```

While compiling it gives the error

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

I am sure the problem is with my definition of a `newcommand` using `\speak` but not sure how to resolve it.

MWE is appended below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dialogue}


% custom commands for speaking

\newcommand*\tchr{{\speak{Teacher}}}
\newcommand*\std{{\speak{Student}}}

\begin{document}


% this works

\begin{dialogue}

\speak{Teacher} This is going to be fun

\speak{Student} How so?

\end{dialogue}

% this doesn't

\begin{dialogue}

\tchr This is going to be fun

\std How so?

\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to complement Matts answer, it is the braces here that is the problem `{\speak{Teacher}}`. `\speak` is implemented as starting a new list item, aka `\item[...]`, but with the extra braces this becomes `{\item[...]}` and not the list cannot see the first item in the dialogue and thus gives an error about text in a list without a `\item`.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation of the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `\newcommand`, I believe the format should be as such:

```
\newcommand{\nameofcommand}{<commandaction>}
```

So in your case, it would look like:

```
\newcommand{\tchr}{\speak{Teacher}}
\newcommand{\std}{\speak{Student}}
```

The problem with your code is that `\speak` should appear at the outer level, and the additional braces hinder its working.